# SAS: Assign the missing values

Tags: merge, sas

I have a strange database that looks like this:

```
Client Order_number Original_number New_number
A      1            .               .
       .            1               2
B      3            .               .
C      4            .               .
       .            3               5
       .            5               6
       .            2               8
       .            4               9
```

Say for client A, he gets assigned an `Order_number`=1. Then for some reason, we had to change is `Order_number` for a `New_number` =2
My objective is to populate the above matrix for the missing blanks in the column `Client` as follow:

```
Client Order_number Original_number New_number
A      1            .               .
A      .            1               2
B      3            .               .
C      4            .               .
B      .            3               5
B      .            5               6
A      .            2               8
C      .            4               9
```

I can't think of an efficient way to do so without using `MERGE`.

Comment: Will the data always be ordered chronologically, and do order ids always increment upwards, like in your example? If so you could use a hash table to maintain the latest client id for each order id.

Comment: yes the order number that is first assigned to a client is always ordered chronologically and ids always increment upwards. good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program works, but it could probably be refactored a bit since I just threw it together.  It assumes that the whole table is sorted like your sample.  It uses hash tables, so if you're processing something big, this might run into memory limitations.

The idea is to build up a couple hash tables as you go so that you have an abstract of what appeared in the lines above.

```
data want (drop=rc map_:);
    if _n_ = 1 then do;
        declare hash orig_new();
        orig_new.definekey('map_original');
        orig_new.definedata('map_new','map_client');
        orig_new.definedone();

        declare hash new_client();
        new_client.definekey('map_new');
        new_client.definedata('map_client');
        new_client.definedone();
    end;

    set have;

    if order ne . then do;
        map_original = order;
        map_new = .;
        map_client = client;
        rc = orig_new.add();
    end;

    if client = '' then do;
        rc = orig_new.find(key:original);
        client = map_client;
    end;

    if new ne . then do;
        map_original = original;
        map_new = new;
        map_client = client;
        rc = orig_new.add();
        rc = new_client.add();
    end;

    rc = new_client.find(key:original);
    client = map_client;

run;
```

(I don't know if this is going to be helpful, but at least I enjoyed the exercise.)

Comment: I will try it out! thanks. Yes my dataset is about 20 gig. Though this hash code should be more efficient than doing some merges.

Comment: I tried your solution but not success...see above my question with your updated code.