# SAS: Hash Object Lookup within the same database

Tags: hash, sas

This question is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145240/sas-assign-the-missing-values). Beside doing merges using hash objects, I am struggling with Hash Objects when it comes to do a lookup within the same database. I have this database where there is a continuous update to the `order_number` of a client:

```
Client Order_number New_number
XYZ    1000         1001
       1001         1002
ABC    1006         1009
       1009         1017
SST    1010         1011
       1017         1020
       1020         1030
       1011         1050
```

Similarly to my previous question, I need the following:

```
Client Order_number New_number
XYZ    1000         1001
XYZ    1001         1002
ABC    1006         1009
ABC    1009         1017
SST    1010         1011
ABC    1017         1020
ABC    1020         1030
SST    1011         1050
```

In other words, when the client name is missing, I use the order_number to match with a previous new_number to find the client.
The orders are first sorted by `order_number` and then `new_number`.

I am trying to achieve the code with some changes to the code posted in my previous question but with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work if your data is a SAS dataset. This example rewrites to the existing dataset. What is does is filter on all observations where the client is known and then loop through the chain of ordernumbers using a hash while the client is empty.

```
data orders (keep=c o n rename=(c=client o=order_number n=new_number));
 length client $8 order_number 8 new_number 8;
 * declare hash object;
 if _n_ = 1 then do;
  declare hash h(dataset:'orders');
  h.definekey('order_number');
  h.definedata('client','new_number');
  h.definedone();
  call missing(client, order_number, new_number);
 end;
 * set statement with rename of original column names;
 set orders (rename=(order_number=o new_number=n client=c) where=(c ne ''));
 * find in hash ;
 rc = h.find(key:n);
 * write first observation;
 output;
 * do loop through chain of order numbers while client is empty;
 do while (rc = 0 and client = '');
  * update values of output dataset;
  o = n;
  n = new_number;
  rc = h.find(key:n);
  * write current observation;
  output;
 end;
run;
```

Comment: Wow that works great! thank you. I am trying to go line by line to make sure I understand what's going on.

Comment: why is the `where=(c ne ''));` necessary in the `set` statement?

Comment: The where is to select the observations where the client is known. This is the start of the chain and it will loop as long as the client is unknown. Removing it will result duplicate ordernumbers in your output. The duplicates will also still miss the client id.